# Move method execution to separate thread and receive return value

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I am rather new to multithreading and the likes and still trying to wrap my head around the whole thing.
I have the following scenario (simplified):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private AppLogic logic = new AppLogic();

    private void GetData()
    {
        var dataSetNames = logic.GetDataSetNames();

        foreach (var dataSetName in dataSetNames)
        {
            var page = new TabPage();
            var dgv = new DataGridView { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, DataSource = logic.GetDataSet(dataSetName) }
            page.Controls.Add(dgv);
            tabControl1.TabPages.Add(page)
        }
    }

    private void GetMeSomeDataToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetData();
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

That's fancy and all but since the part where `logic` gathers data takes a few seconds, the Form will always freeze. I don't want that so I am currently trying to get rid of that. What I tried was changing the `GetData()` call a bit:

```
Task<TabControl> t = Task<TabControl>.Factory.StartNew(GetData);
tabControl1 = t.Result;
```

Of course I adjusted `GetData()` accordingly so it now returns a new `TabControl` instead of accessing the Form directly.
This didn't improve my situation at all, though, which is probably because accessing the `Result` Property of a Task forces the accessing Task to wait for completion.
 
So I am currently looking for a different way to do this but I can't come up with anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the best way would be to use ContinueWith:

```
t.ContinueWith(formerTask => {
    if (formerTask.IsFaulted) return;
    var x = formerTask.Result;
    // do whatever but use Invoke if necessary
})
```

This starts a task to process the result after your task has completed.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to deal with this is to make the eventhandler `async`:

```
private async void GetMeSomeDataToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   TabControl t = await Task<TabControl>.Run(GetData);
   tabControl1 = t;
}
```

Note that the `async void` pattern should generaly be avoided but is Ok for eventhandlers.

This approach is much easier when you need to update your GUI with the returned results. Creating a TabControl on another thread is highly suspect though. You should separate the data-getting and the control-creating. The latter action should be done on the main Thread.

This will unfreeze your GUI but to make this really efficient the GetData method should be made async, and the task.Run replaced by awaiting an I/O method.

Comment: Wasn't it the case that a control could not be initialized on a non-UI thread? Has that changed?

Comment: It can be created but indeed not 'initialized'. I think it only works as long as the Thread avoids needing the HWND handle.

Comment: Gives me a syntax error. Call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Task.Run(Func<Task>)' and 'Task.Run(Action)'

Comment: i think you'll have to tweak your GetData() again. The posted code seems a little inconsistent (does it return void or TabControl ?)

Answer (score -1):

Alright, after some work I found out dryman's answer wasn't optimal for me. This is what I did:

```
private async void GetData()
{    
    tabControl1.TabPages.Clear();

    Task<List<string>> dataSetNames = Task<List<string>>.Factory.StartNew(logic.GetDataSetNames);

    await dataSetNames;

    foreach (var dataSetName in dataSetNames.Result)
    {
        Task<DataTable> sourceTable = Task<DataTable>.Factory.StartNew(() => logic.GetDataSet(dataSetName));

        TabPage page = new TabPage { Name = dataSetName }
        DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView { Dock = DockStyle.Fill }

        dgv.DataSource = await sourceTable;

        page.Controls.Add(dgv);
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(page);
    }
}
```

This even makes my code more DRY, since I don't have to write

```
Task<TabControl> t = Task<TabControl>.Factory.StartNew(GetData);
```

everytime  I want to call GetData().

TL;DR: use `await threadName;` before accessing the Result-property of a thread if you don't want to block your accessing thread.